# Is it possible somehow to create the form for each patrial on the index page in Rails without javascript?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, rendering, ruby-on-rails-4.2

invites_controller.rb

```
def index
  @invites = Invites.all
end
```

invite.rb

```
has_one :answer
```

answers_controller.rb

```
def new
  @invite = Invite.find(params[:invite_id])
  @answer = @invite.build_answer
end

def create
  @invite = Invite.find(params[:invite_id])
  @answer = @invite.create_answer
  redirect_to :back
end
```

answer.rb

```
belongs_to :invite
```

routes.rb

```
resources :invites, only: [:index] do
  resources :answers, only: [:new, :create]
end
```

Is it possible to create invites/index.html where for each line-item will be exist working form for answer without any javascript?

With some logic like this:

```
<% @invites.each do |i| %>
  <%= form_for(i, i.build_answer) do |f| %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :accept, value: true  %>
    <%= f.submit "accept" %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

What are the routing and the rendering of forms will be?

ps: I can solve my problem by creating accept column at Invite model and simply updating each line item like this

```
<% @invites.each do |i| %>
  <%= form_for(i) do |f| %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :accept, value: true  %>
    <%= f.submit "accept" %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

but interesting about other way))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can achieve it as

```
<% @invites.each do |i| %>
  <%= form_for([i,i.answer.build]) do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :name_of_you_answer_field %>
    <%= f.submit %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```